# Read yaml file to vm options with yq

Tags: java, shell, yaml, kubernetes-helm, yq

I have a simple values.yaml file which has below data:

```
...
env:
   - name: GOOGLE_DNS_1
     value: 8.8.8.8
   - name: GOOGLE_DNS_2
     value: 8.8.4.4
   - name: RUN_VARIABLES
     value: "-Xms150m -Xmx300m"
...
```

I would like to construct a string using "yq"like

```
-DGOOGLE_DNS_1="8.8.8.8"
-DGOOGLE_DNS_2="8.8.4.4"
-Xms150m -Xms300m
```

To set my Java VM Options.

Comment: You tagged this as a Helm question, and mention the Helm-standard `values.yaml` file; are you trying to do this with Helm and Kubernetes manifests, or in some other context?  How is the application consuming these settings?

Answer (score 0):

Using [yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```
yq -r '(.env[] | select(.name == "GOOGLE_DNS_1").value) as $dns1
     | (.env[] | select(.name == "GOOGLE_DNS_2").value) as $dns2
     | (.env[] | select(.name == "RUN_VARIABLES").value) as $jvmOpts
     | "-DGOOGLE_DNS_1=\"\($dns1)\" -DGOOGLE_DNS_2=\"\($dns2)\" \($jvmOpts)" '
```

this produces for your input:
`-DGOOGLE_DNS_1="8.8.8.8" -DGOOGLE_DNS_2="8.8.4.4" -Xms150m -Xmx300m`